# Metric Unit Conversion Program in C++

Tags: c++

I"m Learning C++ through "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ 2nd Edition by Bjarne Stroustrup", and I'm curious if there is a better way to do this exercise, using less memory or cpu cycle times.

The program is simple, get a number from the user and convert to desired unit.
Example: User inputs 1km and wants to convert to meters.
So the console display 1km = 1000m.
1cm = 10mm and so on...

Here's my source code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

/* Function : error_buffer_key
 * author: https://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/182128/ 
 * Actions: Check if CIN is in Error State 
 * Input : CIN
 * Return : False = No errors, True = Error with cin
 */

bool error_buffer_key()
{
    if(!cin) 
    {        
        cin.clear();           // Restore input stream to working state
        cin.ignore(100, '\n'); // Get rid of any garbage that user might have entered
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
int main()
{
    vector<string> unidades = { "mm", "cm", "dm", "m", "dam", "hm", "km" }; // Vector unidades
    float numero_dig;                                                       // Number to receive from keyboard
    string unid_dig;                                                        // Metric Unit 1
    string unid_dig2;                                                       // Metric Unit 2
    while(1) {

        do {
            cout << "Input a number for metric conversion : ";
            cin >> numero_dig >> unid_dig; // Receive data
        } while(error_buffer_key());

        cout << "\nInsert the desired unit:\n ";

        for(unsigned char i = 0; i < unidades.size(); i++)
            cout << unidades[i] << ","; // Print Vector to user see
        cout << endl;

        cin >> unid_dig2; // Receives Metric Unit 2

        if(find(unidades.begin(), unidades.end(), unid_dig2) == unidades.end() || //Check for Errors in Metric Unit
            find(unidades.begin(), unidades.end(), unid_dig) == unidades.end()) 
            {
                cout << endl << "Error, Try Again" << endl; 
            } 
            else
            cout << endl
                 << numero_dig << unid_dig << "="   //The Number equals to...
                 << (numero_dig *                   //Number*10^(index of first metric unit - index of second metric unit )
                        pow(10,
                            find(unidades.begin(), unidades.end(), unid_dig) -
                                find(unidades.begin(), unidades.end(), unid_dig2)))
                 << unid_dig2 << endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You might want to ask this over on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Dennis is right, but - it's not clear what exactly you're asking. What do you want to try and improve?  ..

Comment: This hardly uses any memory of cpu cycles as it is.

Comment: I was thinking that my code was not efficient enough.
Thanks Dennis and others, I will repost at code Review.

Comment: Given the problem you're trying to solve, every second you spend optimizing it is a net loss for everything: you, the environment, etc. It's a very simple operation and you're not pessimizing it, and that's all that counts. It's perfectly fine.